# awk partly string match (if column/word partly matches)

Tags: awk

My dummy file looks like this:

```
C1    C2    C3    
1     a     snow   
2     b     snowman 
snow     c     sowman
```

I want to get line if there is string `snow` in $3. I can do this like this:

```
awk '($3=="snow" || $3=="snowman") {print}' dummy_file
```

But there should be more simpler way.

Answer (score 220, accepted):

```
awk '$3 ~ /snow/ { print }' dummy_file
```

Comment: strictly speaking, the print isn't needed: `'$3~/snow/'` suffice

Comment: Sadly that link is already dead: Here is the current link http://shop.oreilly.com/product/9781565924277.do

Comment: Your pattern is "snow", while if there's special symbol, like [ \ " in my case, the index() is a better solution.

Comment: Is there an way to negate the check?  I know we can use 'next' instead of 'print' and print everything else,  but just checking for something with fewer instructions

Comment: use ! so e.g.  awk '$3 !~ /foo/'

Comment: How to print the line number of the matched string. I mean, suppose /String/ is located in line 80, I want to get the line number. Thanks.

Comment: {print NR,$0} will print the "record/line number" and the whole line matched.  Caveat, assuming you only passed one filename to awk.  If you give a list of files as arguments to your awk command, you would want to make sure you are using GNU awk, and change NR to FNR to get the correct line number.

Comment: as an aside while @SheetJS is correct that `{ print }` is not needed, i originally put it in there to show where the "operational part" would go because `$3 ~ /snow/` syntax may unfamiliar to a new user and they may confuse it with "operation" rather than pattern matching part of awk.

Answer (score 58):

Also possible by looking for substring with index() function:

```
awk '(index($3, "snow") != 0) {print}' dummy_file
```

Shorter version:

```
awk 'index($3, "snow")' dummy_file
```

Comment: This is better than Ahmed Masud's answer, because it processes "snow" as  a literal string, not as a regular expression.

Comment: You could write it even simpler: `awk 'index($3, "snow")' dummy_file`

Comment: I agree that this is better than my answer.

Answer (score 13):

Maybe this will help

http://www.math.utah.edu/docs/info/gawk_5.html

```
awk '$3 ~ /snow|snowman/' dummy_file
```

Answer (score 10):

Print lines where the third field is either `snow` or `snowman` only:

```
awk '$3~/^snow(man)?$/' file
```

Answer (score 1):

#### GNU sed

```
sed '/\s*\(\S\+\s\+\)\{2\}\bsnow\(man\)\?\b/!d' file
```

Input:

```
C1    C2    C3    
1     a     snow   
2     b     snowman 
snow     c     sowman
      snow     snow     snowmanx
```

..output:

```
1     a     snow
2     b     snowman
```

Comment: This could not be a more complicated answer to a pretty straight forward question.

Comment: Plus, it is VERY risky to use `sed` for whole words. Albeit technically possible, for that to work reliably, I had to use look-behind, look-forward as well as `!?` constructions when it was about words that should *not* follow. This is nothing for the faint of heart, that's for sure. (And prone to errors that might consume plenty of time to find and fix them.)

Answer (score 0):

It is **far** past the post date, but if you are not married to the `awk` and just want something to pull those lines, you can just use:

```bash
less -f dummy_file | grep snow
```

And I use `less` because `cat` does not handle UTF-8 very well

Note: this will check every line for the presence of `snow`