# Variable based AWK partly string match (if column/word partly matches)

Tags: regex, awk, syntax

> This question comes from [this other](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17001849/awk-partly-string-match-if-column-word-partly-matches).

**Case scenario** for my **Linux shell** script:

```
$ cat test.txt
C1    C2    C3
1     a     snow
2     b     snowman
snow     c     sowman
```

Searching for lines with third field **containing** "snow" works OK:

```
$ awk '$3 ~/snow/' test.txt
1     a     snow
2     b     snowman
```

But I need to do it by **using variables**:

```
$ word="snow"

$ echo $word
snow

$ awk -v variable="snow" '$3 ~/variable/' test.txt

$ awk -v variable="$word" '$3 ~/variable/' test.txt

$
```

As can be seen, there are **no results**.

How could I perform **AWK search variable-based**?

Answer (score 2):

You should change `$3 ~/variable/`  TO `$3 ~ variable` since a `/../` contains regexp not variables. So in your case it will try to search "a string" named variable NOT "a variable" named variable.

Comment: Yes, `/.../` is a regex *literal*. If the pattern is stored in a variable, you don't use the slashes.