# grep a substring in a column and print the rows that contain that substring in that column

Tags: bash

example:

```
a,bee,a bee
c,fee,c dee
e,dee,e bee 
g,hee,d deen
h,aee,t Dee
```

if the block above is a 3x5 data, I want to print the rows that contain 'dee' in the third column, it should be case insensitive and only find the word that matches exactly (for example 'deen' is not acceptable), output should be as follow:

```
c,fee,c dee
h,aee,t Dee
```

how would the Bash command looks like

what I have tried is:

```
awk -F"," '{print $3}' filename | grep -iw 'dee'
```

but I still need the data at column 2.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow (SO). [SO is a question and answer page for professional and enthusiast programmers](https://stackoverflow.com/tour). Please add your own code to your question. You are expected to show at least the amount of research you have put into solving this question yourself.

Comment: `grep -P "^([^,\n]+,){2}[^,\n]+dee$" file`

Comment: If this is a 3x3 table, does it mean that your separator is the comma `,` e.g. the 1st line has elements "a", "bee" and "a bee" (with a whitespace in the last column)?

Comment: correct, "," is the delimiter

Comment: Is this what you are looking for? https://stackoverflow.com/a/17001897/1581658 (with some toLower added in to ignore case)

Comment: @SamBob Similar but  I want to get the rows that contain the word 'dee' but not the whole field is only 'dee', also need to be case insensitive and exactly match the word

Answer (score 1):

Assumed your data is in a file named `dat`, try this:

```
sed -ne '/[dD]ee$/p' dat
```

Or if you like to use `awk`:

```
awk '/[dD]ee$/' dat
```

Or if you like to use `grep`:

```
grep -i 'dee$' dat
```

then the output is

```
c,fee,c dee
h,aee,t Dee
```

Try to explore how to use regular expression to match a pattern.
In your case your regular expression is `[dD]ee$` that matches the pattern `dee` or `Dee` at the end `$` of any line.

Comment: I have tried but the output is only 'h,aee,t Dee'

Answer (score 0):

c.f. https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Regexp.html

```
$: awk -F, 'BEGIN{IGNORECASE=1} $3~/\<dee\>/' file # \< & \> are word boundaries
c,fee,c dee
h,aee,t Dee
```

Or just with `grep` -

```
$: grep -Ei '([^,]+,){2}.*\<dee\>' file # constrain string to 3rd field
c,fee,c dee
h,aee,t Dee
```

Comment: Both method works! Thank you. But I might have to figure out how to use regular expression first to work with my real data. Thanks nonetheless.

Comment: Be careful of the [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info/) when posting a question. Always try to use as close to real data as possible. If you update your question with examples, we can likely help.